# TypeScript will not let me use prevState in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am learning TypeScipt and I have already managed to come to a dead end and TS won't let me go any further. So I have defined my interfaces as below:

```
export interface Test {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
  location: string;
  elements?: Element[];
}

export interface Element {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  referenceFrom: number | string;
  referenceTo: number | string;
  result: number | string;
}
```

I am then using one of the interfaces for below useState hook:

```
const [currentTest, setCurrentTest] = useState<Test | null>(null);
```

And at one point I am trying to use `setCurrentTest` and the `prevState` inside of it, however TypeScript won't let me do that and I am getting below error:

```
Argument of type '(prev: Test | null) => { elements: any[]; id?: number | undefined; date?: Date | undefined; location?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Test | null>'.
  Type '(prev: Test | null) => { elements: any[]; id?: number | undefined; date?: Date | undefined; location?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Test | null) => Test | null'.
    Call signature return types '{ elements: any[]; id?: number | undefined; date?: Date | undefined; location?: string | undefined; }' and 'Test | null' are incompatible.
      The types of 'id' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

The function that I am using this `setCurrentTest` in looks like that:

```
  const handleSubmitForm = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id, name } = results;
    const referenceFrom = Number(results.referenceFrom);
    const referenceTo = Number(results.referenceTo);
    const result = Number(results.result);
    if (
      id &&
      name &&
      referenceFrom > 0 &&
      referenceTo > 0 &&
      referenceFrom < referenceTo &&
      result > 0
    ) {
      setCurrentTest((prev) => ({...prev, elements: [...prev.elements, { id, name, referenceFrom, referenceTo, result }] }));
    }
  };
```

What I understand from this is that the optional `null` in the `Test | null` is causing this issue. Also in the `interface Element` there is this optional `elements?` which is also causing the issue because it can also be `undefined`.

So how can I escape this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't add an initial state to avoid having the null, you can make a validation so it only tries to spread the previous state if it's not null. Like this:

```
setCurrentTest((prev: any) => {
    if (prev) {
        return {...prev, elements: [...prev.elements, {id, name, referenceFrom, referenceTo, result}]};
    }
    return {elements: [{id, name, referenceFrom, referenceTo, result}]};
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me when I added the ```any```. I thought about getting rid of the ```null``` but I have a logic in my component that's working basing on whether the ```currentTest``` is true or false so I had to leave it.